# Exclude the folder contents NOT the folder itself in project.json

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

In `publishOptions` section I need to exclude contents of some folders but the folders must be created empty while deploying. How can I achieve that? `"exclude":["wwwroot/logos/**"]` doesn't work

Comment: Please don't put tags into the title http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: I already added an answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71997486/how-to-exclude-folders-from-visual-studio-2022-webdeploy/75148102#75148102

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, empty folder will not be published. You may create folder manually using postpublish script.

From other site, why you need empty folder at all? If for app purpose - create it programmatically when needed.