# How to exclude folders from Visual Studio 2022 WebDeploy?

Tags: webdeploy, visual-studio-2022

I don't manage to exclude certain folders from Visual Studio 2022 WebDeploy (publish to IIS).

There is a bunch of folders that I do not want to be published to my server (e.g. jquery, bootstrap-icons etc.).

I followed this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment) and ended up with a new xml file. The file is called [MyProjectName].wpp.targets.xml and it is located in the same folder as my [MyProjectName].csproj.

The file looks like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemGroup>
    <ExcludeFromPackageFolders
        Include="wwwroot\lib\jquery;
            wwwroot\lib\jquery-validate;
            wwwroot\lib\jquery-validation-unobtrusive;
            wwwroot\lib\jquery-ajax-unobtrusive;
            wwwroot\lib\popper.js;
            wwwroot\lib\bootstrap-icons">
    </ExcludeFromPackageFolders>
</ItemGroup>
```

On my next Publish, however, all those folders (and included files) are still being copied to my server.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Visual Studio Community 2022, V.17.1.5, with a .NET 6 application.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your {project_name}.csproj file and add the following lines...

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\Files\" Exclude="Files\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

With "wwwroot\Files" being the location of the folder with the files you want to exclude.

This can be anywhere inside your  top level declaration.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.32" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.1.32" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.17">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PCS.BusinessServices\PCS.BusinessServices.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PCS.Common\PCS.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PCS.Data.Services\PCS.Data.Services.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PCS.Data\PCS.Data.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PCS.Encryption\PCS.Encryption.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PCS.PdfEngine\PCS.PdfEngine.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\Files\" Exclude="Files\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup> 

</Project>
```